# Troubleshooting ORA-12012, ORA-02194 and ORA-06512 errors

Tags: oracle, jobs, event

On one of installations I see the following errors during job execution:

alert.log:

> Wed Aug 16 16:57:27  2017
>       Errors in file c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\admin\db\bdump\db_j009_3868.trc:
>       ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 62
>       ORA-02194: event specification syntax error 231 (minor error 283) near '0'
>       ORA-06512: at  line 3

db_j009_3868.trc:

> Dump file c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\admin\db\bdump\db_j009_3868.trc
>      Wed Aug 16 16:57:27 2017
>      ORACLE V10.2.0.5.0 - Production vsnsta=0
>      vsnsql=14 vsnxtr=3
>      Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
>      Windows NT Version V5.2 Service Pack 2
>      CPU                 : 4 - type 586, 1 Physical Cores
>      Process Affinity    : 0x00000000
>      Memory (Avail/Total): Ph:2070M/3581M, Ph+PgF:5885M/7522M, VA:855M/2047M
>      Instance name: db
>
> Redo thread mounted by this instance: 1
>
> Oracle process number: 20
>
> Windows thread id: 3868, image: ORACLE.EXE (J009)
>
> ** SERVICE NAME:(SYS$USERS) 2017-08-16 16:57:27.063
>      ** SESSION ID:(151.997) 2017-08-16 16:57:27.063
>      ** 2017-08-16 16:57:27.063
>      ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 62
>      ORA-02194: event specification syntax error 231 (minor error 283) near '0'
>      ORA-06512: at  line 3

There is almost no information about ORA-02194. What should I do to troubleshoot this error? What do 231, 283 and '0' in the error mesage mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a syntax error in specifying the event.

```
SQL> alter session set events '10046 trace name 0 forever, level 12';
ERROR:
ORA-02194: event specification syntax error 230 (minor error 213) near '0'
```

The correct syntax is:

```
SQL> alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';

Session altered.
```

This was just an example, there are thousands of events. Check the code this job executes.

Comment: Thanks, but the same code works on another server without any errors and it does absolutely nothing related to events (or I am wrong?).

Here is the code that job executes:

    lv_sql :=
      'delete /*+index ('
     || t
     || ', '
     || i
     || ')*/ from '
     || t
     || ' where '
     || c
     || ' <= to_date('''
     || to_char(dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
     || ''',''dd.mm.yyyy'')+1 and '
     || c
     || ' >  to_date('''
     || to_char(dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
     || ''',''dd.mm.yyyy'')';
    
    execute immediate lv_sql;
    
    commit;

Comment: see if there is a db trigger that sets an event for that job owner upon logon.

Comment: @Raj, there are no any such triggers, I've double checked